# Receiving "Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server." after redis installation

Tags: linux, nginx, cache, plesk, redis

I received the following error:

```
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
N: Ignoring file 'plesk.list.ai_back' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename
```

**I followed this guide:**
https://wp-rocket.me/blog/redis-object-caching/

**But then this error occurred:**
sudo echo "extension=redis.so" > /etc/php/7.x/apache2/conf.d/redis.ini
-> Error: no such file or directory
I tried to open 7.4, 7.4.3 and 7.2, but none of them existed.

I don't understand why 7.4.3 didn't exist.
Only 7.2 folder existed, even though I already installed Php 7.4.3 via Plesk.

**After this I tried to install 7.4.3 manually with help of this guide:**
https://joshtronic.com/2013/06/18/installing-php-redis-a-php-extension-for-redis/
I just exchanged the version.

**After that I received the following error while trying to restart nginx via terminal:**

```
root@MyName-plesk-ubuntu:/etc/php# /etc/init.d/nginx restart
[....] Restarting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

**This is nginx.service output**

```
    root@MyName-plesk-ubuntu:~# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-03-23 08:29:07 UTC; 2h 17min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 18211 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 23 08:29:07 MyName-plesk-ubuntu.local systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Mar 23 08:29:07 MyName-plesk-ubuntu.local nginx[18211]: nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:1
Mar 23 08:29:07 MyName-plesk-ubuntu.local nginx[18211]: nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1.1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:1
Mar 23 08:29:07 MyName-plesk-ubuntu.local nginx[18211]: nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1.2" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:1
Mar 23 08:29:07 MyName-plesk-ubuntu.local nginx[18211]: nginx: [emerg] "ssl_prefer_server_ciphers" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:3
Mar 23 08:29:07 MyName-plesk-ubuntu.local nginx[18211]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Mar 23 08:29:07 MyName-plesk-ubuntu.local systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 23 08:29:07 MyName-plesk-ubuntu.local systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 23 08:29:07 MyName-plesk-ubuntu.local systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Do I need to delete that doubled file or rename?
I am new to linux, would be nice if you could explain very detailed.

Thanks for your time.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: Can you provide a copy of /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf

Comment: **ssl.conf**
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM+AES128:EECDH+AESGCM+AES256:EECDH+CHACHA20:EDH+AESGCM+AES128:EDH+AESGCM+AES256:EDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+SHA256+AES128:EECDH+SHA384+AES256:EDH+SHA256+AES128:EDH+SHA256+AES256:EECDH+SHA1+AES128:EECDH+SHA1+AES256:EDH+SHA1$
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;